# Proper way to deal with serial numbers for an inventory catalog

Tags: database, ms-access, comparison, inventory

The end goal is to have data input (various serial numbers) along with data output (various serial numbers) handled such that I can continually update the database with the "remaining data" By this I mean... If my data tables are such that:

```
Input Table 
----------
serial1 
----------
serial2
---------
serial3
----------
serial4
----------
serial5
----------

Output Table
----------
serial1 
----------
serial2
---------
```

I would like to be able to search the database and be able to delete identical datapoints between the two tables so I only have the remaining data as the 'inventory' (The remaining inventory should be serial3, serial4, serial5)

There are two general ways I have thought of to do this...

---

1. Create a count of each datapoint in the input and output table (they will always only be one because each serial number is unique)... then I can theoretically compare the records... if there are two matching data points I can subtract the count of each (creating a count of 0). Finally, I can have code that states that if the combinationcount is 0, delete the corresponding records.

---

2. I can theoretically search the database for identical serial numbers in both input and output table... if there are identical serial numbers, delete record

---

My current issue is how I should go about setting up the tables... I current have two separate databases because I was messing around with ideas...

---

Database1 : each input and output table are unique tables

---

Database2 : the input and output data are in the same table, and therefore represent different fields.

---

Does anybody have an opinion on which database I should start with? I'm not sure which, if either, will give me an advantage when it comes to trying to delete common data points to create a remaining stock count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm silly and was stuck in my line of previous thoughts...

This is simply a union query for 'unmatched records'.

For those who might need it: (following the wizard guidelines)
- query wizard
- select 'find unmatched records' 
- choose the field of each table that you're trying to compare
- run